# MySQL if else statement inside query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this inner query that selects all affiliates linked to the giver user.

```
 (SELECT 
    `realtor_user_id`
 FROM
    `affiliate_assignments`
 WHERE
 `lender_user_id` = `users`.`id`)
```

`affiliate_assignments` structure is:

`id | realtor_user_id | lender_user_id`

where `users` table is joined in outer query and both `realtor_user_id` and `lender_user_id` are foreign keys of `users.id`

I also have user's `role` (selected in outer query) that can be `realtor` or `lender`

What I need is:

```
IF role = 'lender'

 SELECT realtor_user_id 
 FROM affiliate_assignments
 WHERE lender_user_id = users.id

ELSE IF role = 'realtor'

 SELECT lender_user_id
 FROM affiliate_assignments
 WHERE realtor_user_id = users.id

END IF
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: Use CASE in place of IF. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of a question that just says the answer is `case`.  Read the question . . . it involves multiple different columns and correlations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  case  when

```
    select case when role = 'lender' then realtor_user_id 
                when role = 'realtor'  then lender_user_id 
            end  as my_result 
    FROM affiliate_assignments
    WHERE lender_user_id = users.id
```

do the fact you have different where condition  you can rebuil you condition using composite  condition  is when clause

```
select  case  
            when role = 'lender'  AND lender_user_id = users.id  then realtor_user_id 
            when  role = 'realtor' AND realtor_user_id = users.id then lender_user_id
                  ELSE  your_result_for else 
FROM affiliate_assignments
```

Comment: No need for a case in the where clause?

Comment: OP's pseudo-code has `WHERE lender_user_id = users.id` in the first select, and `WHERE realtor_user_id = users.id` in the second.

Comment: Yeah, what about the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Using case statement:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN role = 'lender' THEN realtor_user_id
    WHEN role = 'realtor' THEN lender_user_id
    END CASE 
FROM affiliate_assignments
WHERE realtor_user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this uses `left join`s:

```
select u.*,
       coalesce(aal.realtor_user_id, aar.lender_user_id) as other_user_id
from users u left join
     affiliate_assignments aal
     on u.id = aal.lender_user_id and u.role = 'lender' left join
     affiliate_assignments aar
     on u.id = aar.realtor_user_id and u.role = 'realtor';
```